# Ajax Javascript function not being called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First question on StackOverflow so I hope i get this right. I have a AJAX call to a JS function :

```
function addOptionText(str)
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("0").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","AddText.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

And Here is my HTML code :

```
<body>
    <FORM NAME ="form6" onclick= "addOptionText(this.value)" >
        Text Input:
        <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE placeholder ="Nume Field" NAME ="Text_Field">
        <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Edit" VALUE = "Add" >

    </FORM>
    <p id="0"> </p>
</body>
```

The php file only contains :

```
<html>
    <body>

       <?php
            $name = ($_GET['q']);
            echo "nume";
       ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the function doesn't appear to be used as the paragraph doesn't change. New to php here and trying to understand how it works so I'm thinking something might've slipped me.

EDIT
I had more than one "submit" id's so that's why it didn't work. I changed the "submit" id from  to  and now all's working as intended.

Comment: can you do `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` right before your `document.getElementById` and post the results? (results will be in the console of the developer tools for your browser)

Comment: It was a rogue } in my <script> tag. Thanks it now works :D

Comment: Did you edit in your question, I don't see it. When answering your own question it is nice to provide the fix so others can learn from it.

Comment: It was leftover from another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code is all over the place.

1. `<FORM NAME ="form6" onclick= "addOptionText(this.value)" >` is wrong for a multitude of reasons.
   First, **we don't use onclick on the form itself but on the submit button**. Secondly the value you put in the parameter doesn't in any way represent the value of the text box.
2. Since you want just to display the value of your textbox and not to navigate to a different page, modify your `<form>` tag, so that it doesn't have an `action = "some page"` attribute, because that way it will automatically redirect you to the page you specify and thus the AJAX request is rendered useless. Instead, modify your tag so that it looks like this:

   `<form name = "form6" onsubmit = "return false;">`
   **Provided that you specify your input/button type to submit**: `type= "submit"`, using the `onsubmit` event and setting it to `return false` will prevent the form from sending you over to a new page.
3. When using Vanilla JavaScript and not jQuery, I believe its more efficient to use IDs, so as to identify your HTML elements easier in JavaScript.
4. Your PHP code doesn't mean anything at all. **Before doing anything else, you need to evaluate if, indeed, the q was sent over to the PHP file with the GET method**. To do that, use in your php file:
   `if (isset($_GET["q"])):`
       `// Your code`
   `endif;`
   The line: `echo "nume"` you wrote will output "nume" regardless of what you have actually sent to your php file with the AJAX request.
5. In my opinion is pretty useless to still provide support for `Internet Explorer 5 and 6`. Not many people use it, unless for whatever reason they are mentally bound to it.

---

Analytically, how your files should be:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <form name = "form6" onsubmit = "return false;">
        Text Input:
        <input type = "TEXT" placeholder ="Nume Field" id = "textfield" name = "Text_Field"/>
        <input id = "submit" type= "submit" Name = "Edit" value= "Add"/>
    </form>
    <p id = "0"> </p>
    <script src = "YOUR JAVASCRIPT FILE" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

---

**JavaScript**:

```
var textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function() {
    'use strict';
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("0").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "AddText.php?q=" + textfield.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

---

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["q"])):
        echo ($_GET["q"]);
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Apologies for the newbish question but shouldn't I be calling the function somewhere? Or will Javascript do it by itself whenever the submit button is pressed?

Comment: Not in this case, because it is attached to an event. When you click the submit button the event fires, so the function fires and sends the AJAX request to the PHP file.

Comment: I've tried putting your JS code in and wrapped it in window.onload = function(){}; to make sure all elements load + added in my php file a simple   echo name  to check if the function gets called, but I'm still getting no output.

Comment: Just put the javascript code before the closing body tag. You don't need window.onload().

Comment: If I don't wrap it then I get the error Cannot read property 'Text_Field' of undefined in the console log. This is how the JS looks inside the html file http://pastebin.com/ikQsbVfZ

Comment: I did and but the function is still not called ( as far as I can tell since the "name" string from my php (Which should be called whatever the case) isn't outputed to the screen...

Comment: @dobri252 check out my answer. I saw your comment when I got home, so I changed the entire answer a bit and tested it on my server and it works like a charm.  also changed a few things and explain them better. Check it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional input I kinda got so sidetracked with finishing the project I forgot to actually reply to my own question. The problem was that I had two submit type buttons with the same id and the function didn't know which one to apply to. I have since changed the code and it works quite well so thanks! And the reason I'm puttin in IE functionality is because my teacher is mental about it... Uni projects are "fun"